# Scroll text horizontally in a NSTextView inside NSScrollview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using a NSScrollView with a nested NSTextView to let the user insert and edit a large chunk of text in my OSX application.
[image: Application running]

If i insert some text, the text didn't expand itself into its current line, instead a new line is created and the horizontal scrollbar doesn't expand neither.
How can I resolve this situation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional scroll view. Create a text container of the desired width and set it for the text view (`replaceTextContainer:` or `initWithFrame:textContainer:`). Set `setWidthTracksTextView:` to prevent the container from being resized.

Comment: I am not using any additional scroll view, i'm simply using the "Text View" element selected from the object library

Answer (score 0):

Please try below codes .....

**Objective-C**

```
[self.scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:YES]; 
[self.textView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
[self.textView setHorizontallyResizable:YES];
[[self.textView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:NO];
[[self.textView textContainer] setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
```

**Swift**

```
scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = true
textView.maxSize = NSMakeSize(CGFloat(FLT_MAX), CGFloat(FLT_MAX))
textView.isHorizontallyResizable = true
textView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = false
textView.textContainer?.containerSize = NSMakeSize(CGFloat(FLT_MAX), CGFloat(FLT_MAX))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension on NSTextView

```
extension NSTextView {
    func wrapText(_ isWrapped: Bool) {
        guard let scrollView = enclosingScrollView else { return }
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = !isWrapped
        isHorizontallyResizable = !isWrapped
        let width = isWrapped ? Int(scrollView.contentSize.width) : Int.max
        maxSize = NSSize(width: width, height: Int.max)
        textContainer?.size = NSSize(width: width, height: Int.max)
        textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = isWrapped
    }
}
```